# SyntaxError: 'await' outside function even tho it is inside a async

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my first ever discord bot in python, it's an economy bot but it says that I cannot use the await function and I don't know why.

```
@bot.command()
async def withdraw(ctx,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

  if amount == None:
      await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount")
      return
  
bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

amount = int(amount)
if amount>bal[1]:
    await ctx.send("You don't have enough potatoes!")
    return
if amount<0:
    await ctx.send("Can only send positive potatoes! No negative!")
    return

await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")

await ctx.send(f"You withdrew {amount} potatoes!")
```

Comment: If this is discord.rewritten, then either don't use async, or make sure you're on the correct python version.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so i see 2 problems. The first one is that the `@bot.command` has to be aligned with `async def` and 2nd you have 6 await functions. Please specify which await function is giving you the error.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer was just to align `@bot.command` and `async def`

Comment: And, presumably to correct the rest of the indentation issues.  You cannot use an `await()` outside the `async def ...` function.   Your lines from

    `bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)`

(which is not indented at all) onwards are outside the function, so these six awaits were throwing compile errors.

Comment: Please click the checkmark on my answer so this issue has an answer